What are all the implications for the target API level (34) requested on the playstore?
I would like to ask for some clarification about the playstore request to upgrade to android 14 (API 34). Having found little information on the internet, I find myself with an application freshly put on the playstore that already asks me for an update. Could someone explain in detail all the steps to follow for a React-native application.
buildscript {
ext {
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 33
targetSdkVersion = 33

I mean that you should not just change the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion by hand to 34 in the build.gradle ... that would be too easy.
Do you necessarily have to upgrade the RN version? (because it is really no longer compatible with android 14? what versions are still valid? what are the compatibilities? )
I have version 0.68.1 installed, and about 30 libraries, some of which may have even been recently abandoned.
Should I only upgrade to 0.70? or should I go straight to 0.74? at the risk of spending a month debugging? or do it one by one? Just with the upgrade-helper it should work easy?
Anyway, I wanted to know if someone brave could explain in detail all the steps I will have to go through?
Useful links are also welcome.

first of all you must check your gradew version, if its support 34 api then u need to upgrade ur buildToolsVers,compileSdkVers and targetsdkVers to 34 if version doesn't support 34 api , I recommend u to use 8.1.0 of grade version
“dependencies { classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0") }”

updated ext
buildscript {
 ext {
  buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
  minSdkVersion = 21
  compileSdkVersion = 34
  targetSdkVersion = 34


if you want to upgrade rn version, I prefer to create new rn app and just copy paste ur src file and codes that have in native side , it will cause less bugs & problems then upgrading directly in your repo. in last RN 74 there is automatically 34 api, so you can go with that
